# Number of generators of an induced ideal of an irreducible component

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, finitely-generated

Recently I am working on algebraic geometry. In dealing with a problem, I need the following:

If $\alpha$ is an ideal generated by $r$ elements of the ring $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, suppose $Y$ is an irreducible component of $Z(\alpha)$, then $I(Y)$ is also generated by $r$ elements of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.

Here $Z(\alpha)$ is the set of points in an affine space that vanish with the evaluation by all elements in $\alpha$ and $I(Y)$ is an ideal of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ that vanish at all points of $Y$. By irreducible I mean cannot be further decomposed into distinct closed subsets in terms of Zariski topology.

Is there any way to prove or disprove it? In case it is not correct, is there any related proposition?

Comment: I think you may be able to use Krull's [Hauptidealsatz](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supDim.pdf).

Comment: I know the lemma, but I could not construct explicitly the implication (in case it is correct)

Comment: That's not true. **Example 1:** Let $n=3$, $\alpha = (xy,xz,yz)$. The irreducible components are the axes; for each axis the ideal is generated by $2$ elements rather than $3$. **Example 2:** Let $n=4$, $\alpha = (x_1^2-x_0 x_2, x_2^2-x_1 x_3)$. Then $Z(\alpha)$ is the (cone over the) union of a twisted cubic and a line. The ideal of the twisted cubic is generated by $3$ elements rather than $2$. These examples show $I(Y)$ can be generated by more, or fewer, elements than $\alpha$.

Comment: "Let $I \subseteq k[x_1, \cdots ,x_n]$ be an ideal generated by $r$ elements ($k = \overline{k}$). Then every irreducible component of $Z(I)$ has dimension $\geq n-r$." (R. Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, Chapter I, Exercise 1.9) This could be a possible refinement of your statement.

Comment: @Krish that is the problem I would like to solve. For my proof, I am missing the statement questioned